# Python: google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Using a service account & it's generated json key file, I'm trying to query a BigQuery table that is connected to an external Google Sheet. The service account has editor/viewer access and I've tried to enable the scope for Drive APIs as I've seen in other questions related to this one. The Google Drive API is also enabled in IAM for the project. Keep getting error: `google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.`

**CODE**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas as pd

# Initialize BigQuery client
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("service_account_file.json")
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)

gbq_staging_table = "Table ID" # dataset.table

query = f"""
SELECT * FROM `{gbq_staging_table}`
"""
staging_df = client.query(query).to_dataframe()
```

**service_account_file.json**

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "projectid",
  "private_key_id": "xxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "client_email": "serviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/xxxxx",
  "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scopes` needs to be passed to `from_service_account_file()` instead of within the `service_account_file.json` file itself.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("service_account_file.json",  scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"])
```